# How to open a webpage that requires Adobe Flash?

Tags: flash, adobe

Adobe Flash is obsolete, but some legacy web pages are using it.

Using the current popular browsers(Google Chrome, FireFox, Microsoft Edge, ...), how can I open the webpage that requires Adobe Flash? I tried looking to download an Adobe Flash, but I couldn't find a stable download address.

Comment: No point asking a question like this. _"What should I download"_ could mean anything from asking about a download for your device (but no actual OS is mentioned), to meaning you want an add-on (but no actual browser is mentioned). Who can Answer you like this?..

Comment: **(1)** Did you know that Flash apps are in `.swf` format? Find that SWF link and try re-using it with [Ruffle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75245513/2057709) in your own HTML code. **(2)** Try find an old copy Chrome browser, which had Flashplayer built-in and download it. **(3)** Try to find a copy of Flash Player **standalone version** (it runs SWF from desktop without needing to be a browser plugin).

Answer (score 3):

**Windows**

1. Open **Microsoft Edge**.
2. Press **Alt + F** or click **...(Setting and more)** button in the upper right corner.
3. Click **Settings**.
4. Click **Default browser** item in the left side bar.
5. In **Internet Explorer compatibility** group, Select **Allow** for **Allow sites to be reloaded in Internet Explorer mode (IE mode)**.
6. Restart **Microsoft Edge**.
7. Open your target URL (needed Adobe Flash Player).
8. Press **Alt + F** or click **...(Setting and more)** button in the upper right corner.
9. Click **Reload in Internet Explorer mode**.